# Is there a way to let Apollo Client globally insert empty strings during loading?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client to receive the GraphQL data for my application. Over time, I see a pattern emerging where for every value I'm querying, I have to include a conditional statement to handle the moment where my data is still loading.

Assume a query looks like this:

```
query TestQuery($userId: Int!) {
  getUser(id: $userId) {
    name
  }
}
```

Then, in every place where I want to display the user name, I have to write something like:

```
{ !this.props.data.loading && this.props.data.getUser.name }
```

or

```
{ this.props.data.getUser && this.props.data.getUser.name }
```

I don't want to display "Loading..." or a rotating spinner in any of these places. Is there a way to avoid this conditional statement by globally replacing all `this.props.data.x.y.z` values with `null` or an empty String during loading?

- If so, how? Would this be considered an antipattern or bad practice?
- If not, which of the above two forms is preferred?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
class GraphqlComponent extends React.Component {
    renderError(){
        // ...
    }

    renderLoading(){
        // ...
    }

    renderLoaded(){

    }

    render(){
        const { loading, error } = this.props;
        if(error){
            return renderError();
        }
        if(loading){
            return renderLoading();
        }
        return renderLoaded();
    }
}

class MyComponent extends GraphqlComponent{
    renderLoaded(){
        // your logic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've mixed up `renderError()` and `renderLoading()`; other than that, this might work! Thanks.

Comment: @Bart Thank you! Fixed.